# Getting weird characters in an add-in form

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Our Excel add-in project incorporates several winforms, which display perfectly on all user workstations except for one. On this particular workstation, the label text on the winforms are garbled into unintelligible characters (see screenshot). The strange thing is, text that's in any textbox controls are fine. The user's regional setting is en-US, no other locales on that workstation.

We've ruled out regional settings and corrupt fonts. Any ideas what might be causing this? What form properties, or project settings, should we be looking at which could help us?

[image: Partial screenshot]

Comment: At least mention what it is supposed to say.

Comment: LOL! It's supposed to list the application name and version. I can't tell you any more, because of confidentiality issues.

Comment: Can we assume that the text is DBCS and the workstation is doesn't display on is an older OS, like XP?

Comment: @Otaku, the OS is WinXP, SP2. Not DBCS, since it's en-US locale. No Asian locales installed either.

Comment: Can you put in non-confidential text such as "line 1: the title" and "line 2: the text" and post another screen shot of what that looks like?

Comment: It's not a 64 bit / 32 bit issue is it? Is this one workstation running 64 bit office and the forms are targetted at 32 bit?

Answer (score 0):

does your title and version contain formatted text? is the text the same each time you start the application? Can you copy/paste the code that prints/sets the title and version?